# What is the correct way to write asyncio code for use with AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-asyncio

I wrote the following code:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def get_urls(event):

    return {'msg':'Hello World'}

def lambda_handler(event,context):

    return loop.run_until_complete(get_urls(event))
```

I was trying to accomplish the following but faster.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {'msg':'Hello World'}
```

What was the correct way to write this in an AWS Lambda environment?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 22):

Works for me... You need to choose Runtime "Python 3.6" or "Python 3.7".

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def get_urls(event):
    return {'msg':'Hello World'}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return loop.run_until_complete(get_urls(event))
```

[image]

Comment: AWS lambda best practices suggests to "Initialize database connections outside of the function handler".. 
How do you create a database connection in a code like this? Is it possible to create a database connection outside of the function handler?

Comment: @givo Yes. Python executes any "outside code" (code at the leftmost level, outside any functions or classes) during import time.
Another option is to use global variable to hold the connection and initialize it in the handler function only if it was not initialized yet.

Comment: Thanks @Messa, with the runtime you saved me hours of headache.

Comment: Aggressively spinning up things that you are going to need when processing requests is an important optimzation strategy for AWS lambda server implementations. AWS recommendation doesn't go far enough, you should do it for more than just database connections. Also, if you don't reuse objects in subsequent requests, your performance will be terrible. Remember the things you create and reuse them next time if you can.

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3.7+ you can use `asyncio.run()` to execute your coroutines:

```
import asyncio

# The AWS Lambda handler
def handler(event, context):
    asyncio.run(main())

async def main():
    # Here you can await any awaitable
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.gather([coroutine_1, coroutine_2])
```

Here's a full example of how to develop, test and deploy an asynchronous Python function using asyncio, aiohttp and aiobotocore on AWS Lambda: https://github.com/geeogi/async-python-lambda-template

Comment: I think this is wrong, at least if you are reusing global resources across Lambda invocations. When I use `asyncio.run`, I get "event loop closed" errors on subsequent runs. I guess this is because those global resources are tied to the previous event loop?

Comment: @mariaines is right. I just finished trouble shooting a bug caused by using asyncio.run() on AWS Lambda. asyncio.get_event_loop() seems to be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Asynchronous execution does many things at the same time. You're only doing one thing. You can't do one thing faster than the time it takes to do one thing. Asynchronous execution allows you to perform independent tasks that would normally execute one after another(synchronously) at the same time and then return the result of all the tasks. Inherently, you have to be performing more than one operation.

Comment: You are correct, but there are cases you can benefit from async in an AWS lambda.  For example, when your function aggregates results from multiple HTTP endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Need to install aioboto3 locally as a part of deployment zip package
`

```
import asyncio
import aioboto3



async def list_s3_objs (bucket):
    async with aioboto3.client("s3") as s3_client:
        objs = await s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)
    return objs['Contents']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(list_s3_objs('bucket_name'))
```

`